# appending HTML syntax in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to generate HTML code by taking input from the textarea.

**HTML**

```
<textarea></textarea>
<div class="submit">submit</div>
```

**Jquery**

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $(".submit").click(function(){
        var q = $("textarea").val();
        $("body").append("<div class="yo">" + q + "</div>");
    })
})
```

for example, after 3 clicks on submit button, the output should be in this form

```
 <div class="yo"> first value </div> 
 <div class="yo"> second value </div> 
 <div class="yo"> third value </div>
```

Although text() method gives output in HTML format, next click replaces the earlier values. I need to print HTML lines one after another as many times I want. How do I achieve this ?

**Fiddle** 
http://jsfiddle.net/sagesony/azzLn/

Comment: Firstly, you have unmatched quotes in your code example. Your fiddle however would work fine, you just need to select jQuery from the library list on the left: http://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/azzLn/1/

Comment: No problem with your fiddle. What is your issue?

Comment: I think you didn't understand my problem. If user puts value "hello" in the textarea, I need that value as "<div>Hello </div>" and not as just "Hello".

Comment: @user3279367 so you want to see the HTML typed, not actually create the DOM elements?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/azzLn/2/

Answer (score 0):

Replace click by the newer on(), which is the suggested one to use in all latest query releases.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    $(".submit").on("click", function(){
      var q = $("textarea").val();
      $("body").append("<div>" + q + "</div>");
    });
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/azzLn/5/

Answer (score -1):

**UPDATED**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $(".submit").click(function(){
            var q = $("textarea").val();
            $("body").append('<div class="yo">' + q + '</div>');
        })
    });
```